# Is there a better way of doing it,

Tags: haskell, monads

```
maximum' :: [Writer [Int] Int] -> Writer [Int] Int
maximum' xs = writer (maximumBy (comparing fst) (map runWriter xs))
```

If I use sequence then all the transcripts will be merged in the maximum transcript which I don't want, it can be done if I use runWriter but is there a way of doing it without it?
Thanks!

Comment: One small change: You can replace `cmp` with `(compareBy fst)`.

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for something like that, this seemed to clumsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicit building of writer results and reconstruction of selected writer you may simplify the code this way:

```
maximum' :: [Writer [Int] Int] -> Writer [Int] Int
maximum' = maximumBy (comparing $ fst . runWriter)
```